# React styled-component, animation: invert the position of two divs

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, jsx, styled-components

I tried to see a lot of materials about it but I didn't find an answer that could really help me to figure out on how to solve this problem. At the end of the post you will find the documentation and the links that i saw.

***Problem***

I've this form and my goal is to make an animation that invert the position of the two column: so the right column will go on the right part, the white column on the left. This animation will start only when i click the button `Sign up`.

[image]

***Code***

```
import React, {setState, useState} from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Form from '../../components/Form/index'; 

const Row = styled.div `
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: 'row';
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 0px #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
`

const Column = styled.div `
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px; 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  height: 500px; 
  background:linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) ), url(https://i.ibb.co/YcXymy8/green-Login-Background.jpg);
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 30px;

const DoubleColumn = styled.div `
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 2;
  align-items: center;
`

const Title = styled.h1 `
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align:center;
`
const P = styled.p `
  color: white;
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
`

const Button = styled.button `

  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: Transparent;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  &:focus {
    outline: 0;
  }
  &:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #089B52;
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 10px 1px #000;
  }
  &:active {
    width: 177px;
    height: 48px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px;
  }
`

const ButtonContainer = styled.div `
  display:flex;
  align-content:center;
  justify-content:center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 180px;
`

function SignIn() {
  const [signUp, setSignUp] = useState(true);


  return (
    <Row signUp={signUp}>
        <Column>
          <Title>Welcome Back</Title>
            <P>Enter to see your tables and your plan. Are you new ? click on the button below!</P>
          <ButtonContainer>
            <Button onClick = {() => setSignUp(!signUp)}>Sign up</Button>
          </ButtonContainer>
        </Column>
        <DoubleColumn>
          <Form />
        </DoubleColumn>
      </Row>
  )
}

export default SignIn;
```

***My tries***

I was thinking to change the direction of the `row` into `row-reverse`, but this property isn't animatable, the same for align-self.

Now i cannot figure how to do it.

***Consideration and visited links***

I organized the login in two differents view, one for signUp and one for SignIn, maybe can i animate between routing two components ?

[styled component docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics)

[guide about animation](https://codeburst.io/animating-react-components-with-css-and-styled-components-cc5a0585f105)

[css-tricks guide on animation](https://css-tricks.com/animating-between-views-in-react/)

Comment: maybe react-transition-group could be a solution ?

Comment: you could use 2 keyframes and `transform: translateY(100%)` or `transform: translateY(-100%)` maybe adjust the percent values

Comment: Hello Rebecca, i used your advice and it works. if you want to write the answer i will sign it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use 2 `keyframes` and animate `transform: translateY(100%)` or `transform: translateY(-100%)` (adjust the percent values) for the respecting components